# What is the "Saves" option used for?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I have noticed that on the left hand margin there is a tab entitled "Saves". What exactly does or can one save there. What is this feature's intended use?

Comment: They're bookmarks in more usual terminology, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/263383

Comment: And why do we have three different ways to hold onto a post we want to revisit located in two completely different places on our profile page: "saves->all saves," "saves->for later," and "activity->following." that's not an actual question, I just think its silly.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/saves

Comment: FYI 'saves' was called 'favorites' in the past.